# How to tell Mockito to use real (unmocked) version of a helper class?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, mockito

With Mockito, I'm used to injecting Mocks into a single class-under-test as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest() {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Mock
    private OtherClass1 mockedClass1UsedByMyClass;

    @Mock
    private OtherClass2 mockedClass2UsedByMyClass;
```

But let's say `MyClass` also uses a simple class `HelperClass`, which provides some simple "helper" methods and doesn't have any further dependencies:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private OtherClass1 otherClass1;

    @Autowired
    private OtherClass2 otherClass2;

    @Autowired
    private HelperClass helperClass; // Don't want to mock this one...
```

Would rather use the real version of this class rather than trying to mock out everything being returned as all it's doing is some simple, deterministic processing. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to take advantage of the `@InjectMocks` then use a [@Spy](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.13/org/mockito/Spy.html).. by default it will use original impl and you can hand-pick the methods you want to mock:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest() {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Mock
    private OtherClass1 mockedClass1UsedByMyClass;

    @Spy
    private HelperClass helperClass;

    @Mock
    private OtherClass2 mockedClass2UsedByMyClass;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! (The only thing I had to do differently was to explicitly specify the impl class instead of the interface as in the real code some of these mocked classes were actually interfaces and unlike `@Mock` it turns out that `@Spy` only works with classes.)

Comment: Yes, if your HelperClass is an interface, you have to user one of your implementations. If you want to be able to use different implementations for different test cases then you would need to craete a spy() manually inside each class and use probably a setter of the MyClass to inject it manually